# How to solve a value of K for a root locus?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

I'm using the book "**Control Systems Engineering - Norman S. Nise**" and in the Root Locus chapter most of the exersices are solved using software.

I'm aware that this is a practical solution to real problems, however I'm curious how can I get a closed form solution to problems of the type :

Find a value of K for which the poles of **the negative feedback closed-loop system** would have a $\zeta = 0.707 $

Assume the open loop transfer function is

$$ G(s) = \frac{K(s-1)(s-2)}{(s+1)(s+2)} $$
$$ H(s) = 1 $$

[image]

Comment: What is $\zeta$, is that the damping ratio, zero, or pole? What is $G$ and $H$, if $G$ is the plant then what is $H$?

Comment: $\zeta$ is the damping ratio. G is the plant and H is the feedback transfer function. Let me see if I can add a image to the question

Comment: Also, where is $K$? Should $H(s) = K$?

Comment: Good point. I've just pasted a common feedback system on the post. Let me edit the post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed-loop transfer function is,
\begin{align}
y &= G(x-z) \\
&= G(x-Hy) \\
(1+GH)y &= Gx \\
y &= \frac{G}{1+GH}x
\end{align}
Let $n_G$, $n_H$ be the numerator of $G$ and $H$, and $d_G$, $d_H$ be the denominator of $G$ and $H$.

\begin{align}
y &= \frac{G}{1+GH}x \\
&= \frac{\frac{n_G}{d_G}}{1+\frac{n_G}{d_G}\frac{n_H}{d_H}}x \\
&= \frac{n_Gd_H}{n_Gn_H + d_Gd_H}x \\
&= \frac{K(s-1)(s-2)}{K(s-1)(s-2) + (s+1)(s+2)}x \\
&= \frac{K(s-1)(s-2)}{K(s^2-3s+2) + (s^2+3s+2)}x \\
&= \frac{K(s-1)(s-2)}{(1+K)\left[s^2+\frac{3(1-K)}{1+K}s+\frac{2+K}{1+K}\right]}x
\end{align}

$\omega_n^2 = \frac{2+K}{1+K}$ and $2\zeta\omega_n = \frac{3(1-K)}{1+K}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\zeta &= \frac{3(1-K)}{2\omega_n} = \frac{3(1-K)}{2\sqrt{2+K}\sqrt{1+K}}
\end{align}

If you want $\zeta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ then $K= \frac{12-\sqrt{109}}{7} $

Comment: What about that gain on the denominator ? $$ (1+K) s^2$$

Comment: oops, I forgot to factor that term out.